# SSIS Agent job keeps running as "inprogress"

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, agent

I have a SSIS package that monitors a folder. This package will run continuously until it's terminated.

I want to schedule this using a SQL Agent job.This SQL Agent job will utilize two steps. It is kind of heart beat job to to make sure the SSIS package runs.

Step - 1 it checks whether the SSIS package is running. if running quit else step 2.
Step - 2 Execute the SSIS job. if OK then report success and quit else report failure and quit.

uses a daily schedule Mon-Fri every 4 hrs.

When I execute the SQL Job, it starts the SSIS package but the job keeps running and the job monitor and history shows it as "inprogress"

I had to close the job to come out of the dialog but in background the SSIS job is still running as expected.

Is this normal behavior ? Do I need to approach this in a different way ?

Appreciate any pointers or help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the job has begun, the Start Jobs dialog box has no impact whatsoever on the running of the job itself - it exists solely to provide a monitoring window for you.  Closing it will have no effect on the running job.

[image]

From other phrases in your question, I gather that you do not expect the job to ever 'finish' - therefore I would expect it to always show as `In Progress` unless it errors out or is stopped.

> "This package will run continuously until it's terminated."
>
> "The job keeps running and the job monitor and history shows it as in progress"

Comment: Thanks , Yes your observations are correct. So I believe this is the expected behavior ..when we schedule a continuously running SSIS package using SQL Agent.